# How to open a URL in new window using WebBrowser control in c# Windows Forms application and read its header information (via regex etc)

Tags: c#, regex, url, webbrowser-control, navigateurl

As said, I would like to open a URL in a new window (not the default IE browser instance of WebBrowser control) and read the Header information in order to retrieve a token.
Currently, I am using the below code that opens in a new IE instance.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(myLink, true);
```

If I use the below code,

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(myLink));
```

it opens in the current window, I need it to open in a new WINDOW.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new form with just the web browser and call it from your current form.

Comment: Thank You. I added the below code in the button click event which worked fine.
`webBrowser1 WebForm = new webBrowser1();
                WebForm.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 0):

u can use this code for open in a new window:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(url.SettingsValue, "_blank", post, headers);
```

1. Parameter => url.SettingsValue = your url address
2. Parameter => "_blank" = for new blank
3. Parameter => post (your choice) = your token or password
4. Parameter => headers (your choice) = token header like => "Authorization: Basic " + auth + "\r\n";

Comment: You should format the answer to be more readable to your audience.

Comment: Sure this is much better